# Is it correct to say "I feel Turk" or "I feel Finn"?

Tags: word-usage

Phrases like "I feel Spanish", "I feel American" etc are widely used. Since "Turk" and "Finn" are non-suffix names of nationalities, is it still correct to say "I feel Turk" or "I feel Finn"?

Comment: "Turk" and "Finn" are the same POS as " Spanish" and "American".

Comment: @Kris: And what POS is that? "American" can be a noun or an adjective. The separate words "Turkish" and "Finnish" exist.

Comment: I've never seen or heard a phrase like "I feel Spanish" or "I feel American", so I don't think such phrases are widely used.  I would take "I am Spanish" to mean that the speaker is a citizen of,  or otherwise closely connected with, Spain.  "Spaniard" in this sense is somewhat old-fashioned.  I would also say either "I am *a* Turk/ *a* Finn" [note the *a*], or else "I am Turkish/Finnish".

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

In this use, *feel* requires an adjectival complement.

*Spanish* is used only as an adjective (except elliptically to refer to the *Spanish [language]*): we say *He is a Spaniard*, not **He is a Spanish*. *American* can be used as either an adjective or a noun. But *Turk* and *Finn* are employed only as nouns—*He is a Turk*, *They are Finns*, but not **He is Turk*, **He is Finn*; these require *Turkish* and *Finnish*. Consequently, *Turk* and *Finn* are not used as complements of *feel*.

Comment: Another construction where *Spanish* looks like a noun is the definite plural "the Spanish", which is used to refer to Spanish people in general (although there is another construction "the Spaniards" which clearly contains a plural noun and might be more common than "the Spanish"--judging from Ngram results for "the Spanish are" vs. "the Spaniards are", the latter was definitely was more common in the past, but it's unclear to me if this remains true in the present).

Comment: @sumelic Fersher. I tend to regard these uses as what CGEL calls 'fused-head' constructions, where the head of the NP is left implicit.

Comment: As a UK native speaker, 'Spaniard' is howlingly archaic.

Comment: @StoneyB I'm not a linguist; trying to understand [your comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/450807/is-it-correct-to-say-i-feel-turk-or-i-feel-finn#comment1085039_450810). How can something be a fused head when said head is left implicit? Or are those (references to) different heads?

Comment: Could you cite your sources?

Comment: @Kris CGEL 5.9.1, p 410. "Fused-head NPs are those where the head is combined with a dependent function that in ordinary NPs is adjacent to the head, usually determiner or internal modifier: [i] Where are the sausages? Did you buy **some** yesterday? [determiner-head] [ii] The first candidate performed well, but the **second** did not.[modifier-head]" . . . The head is 'fused' with its determiner or modifier.

Comment: That ought to be in the answer rather than as an obscure comment.